# The Problem with SSH key while Pushing repository in GitHub

Tags: git, github

Do I need to to get the SSH key every time I push repository into git hub from git? If not how can push the repository with the same SSH key?

Comment: What do you mean by `get the SSH key every time`?

Comment: If my answer answers you question, please mark it as answered by clicking on the tick mark below the voting buttons on my answer. If not please make your question more precise.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "get the ssh key" you mean that you have to do

```sh
ssh-add path/to/private/key
Password Prompt
```

every time you log into a new session. If you don't use a package like [ubuntu keyring](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/), you'll have to manually load your private key in each session. You can make this easier by creating an [ssh_config file](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config) like this:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile /home/USERNAME/.ssh/github_private_key
```

And place this into `/home/USERNAME/.ssh/config` and you public and private key into the same folder. Then you should only be queried for the password when you use it, without having to bother with the ssh-agent separately.

If however, you mean being asked for your github username and password everytime, yes HTTPS-git will always ask for your credentials. Just set up ssh-keys as above and register the public key with github; if you don't specify a password for the private key(not recommended), you won't be asked for a password again when pushing-pulling to/from github. Also see [this guide on github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

HTH